# Java - Variable Check if Contains

Tags: java, variables, contains

I think what I want to do is rather simple, but not sure.  I'd like to do this in the easiest way as I have multiple different variables I want to apply this to.  I want to search if a variable contains a certain word or words and then if it does set a new variable.  For example if someone signs up for email and they have Gmail, I want to set a new variable for use later.  I'm self taught and obviously new to java and would appreciate any feedback.  Thanks.

```
if (email == "*@gmail.com") 
{
    var mailtype = "gmail"
};
```

Another example would be to verify email address format:

```
if (email == "*@*.*") 
{
    var mailformat = "okay"
};
```

Comment: What you are looking for  is regualar expressions or short regex.

Comment: Lookup regexes and don't use `==` to compare Strings!

Comment: _var mailtype_: is this Javascript?

Comment: @Reimeus could be C# ;)

Comment: `.equals()` is better than `==` and [here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Comment: thanks for the tips.  I ended up using:

if (emailinput.indexOf("gmail") !=-1) {var mailtype = "gmail"};

Is there any reason I shouldn't do it this way?  Thanks for all the help.
D.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way, since you are just getting started, to do this is:

```
if( email.toLowerCase().endsWith("@gmail.com") ) {
  mailtype = "gmail";
}
else if( email.toLowerCase().endsWith("@yahoo.com") ) {
  mailtype = "yahoo";
}
else {
  mailtype = "okay";
}
```

But this being said, you will want to take a look at regular expressions and learn how to do this in a more solid and expandable way with matching groups.